# How to use componentName in fragment (Kotlin)?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to implement search function on two different fragments with list. When i try to use the code below, it throws Unresolved reference with **componentName**.
How to solve this?

**ListFragment.kt**

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.note_menu, menu)
        val searchManager = context?.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE) as SearchManager

searchView = menu?.findItem(R.id.search_ic)
    ?.actionView as SearchView
searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
    .getSearchableInfo(componentName))
searchView.maxWidth = Integer.MAX_VALUE
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
    override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
        dailyAdapter.filter.filter(query)
        return false
    }

    override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
        dailyAdapter.filter.filter(newText)
        return false
    }

})
return true
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the problem is you cannot use the components of activity in the fragment. For using components of activity you have to use requireActivity() method.
So your code should be like.

```
 searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(requireActivity().componentName))
```